# Fallback for self hosted vscode extention marketplace?

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-code-server

When hosting a [code-marketplace](https://github.com/coder/code-marketplace) server locally, how would one / is it possible to use the official vscode marketplace as a fall back if yours does not have the extension you are trying to download, kind of like how artifactory can use a fall back when you don't have what you are trying to download?

I have tried googling this and reading the doc for VSCode marketplace as well as the docs for open-source marketplace but I have not found a way of pulling this off